# PHP 5.5.12 Illegal string offset On A Valid Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm receiving an "Illegal string offset" error on an array that has the key I'm trying to access:

PHP version 5.5.12

This causes the error:

```
$avg = $season['avg'];
```

Here's the result of var_dump($season):

```
array (size=38)
    'hr' => string '4' (length=1)
    'gidp' => string '2' (length=1)
    'irs' => string '0' (length=1)
    'np' => string '819' (length=3)
    'team_count' => string '1' (length=1)
    'era' => string '2.13' (length=4)
    'sport_code' => string 'mlb' (length=3)
    'sho' => string '0' (length=1)
    'bk' => string '0' (length=1)
    'sport_id' => string '1' (length=1)
    'sv' => string '0' (length=1)
    'avg' => string '.216' (length=4)
    'whip' => string '0.88' (length=4)
    'bb' => string '6' (length=1)
    'ir' => string '0' (length=1)
    'g' => string '9' (length=1)
    'so' => string '39' (length=2)
    'tbf' => string '244' (length=3)
    'wp' => string '1' (length=1)
    'sport' => string 'MLB' (length=3)
    'l' => string '2' (length=1)
    'svo' => string '0' (length=1)
    'hb' => string '3' (length=1)
    'h' => string '50' (length=2)
    'ip' => string '63.1' (length=4)
    'w' => string '4' (length=1)
    's' => string '561' (length=3)
    'ao' => string '46' (length=2)
    'season' => string '2014' (length=4)
    'r' => string '17' (length=2)
    'go_ao' => string '2.17' (length=4)
    'cg' => string '1' (length=1)
    'player_id' => string '218596' (length=6)
    'ab' => string '231' (length=3)
    'gs' => string '9' (length=1)
    'ibb' => string '1' (length=1)
    'er' => string '15' (length=2)
    'go' => string '100' (length=3);
```

This array was stripped out of a larger array that was created via using json_decode on a web request. I was able to access the parent arrays of data to extract it.

I'm at a loss. I've tried casting it. gettype returns 'array'. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

//EDIT:

I simplified the above question. Here's a more accurate example:

```
public function getPitcherAvg($id)
{
    $stats = $this->getPitcherStats($id);
    $stats = $stats['sport_pitching_composed']['sport_pitching_agg']['queryResults']['row'];

    foreach ($stats as $season)
    {
        if ($season['season'] == 2014)
        {
            $avg = $season['avg'];
        }
    }

    return $avg;
}


public function getPitcherStats($id)
{
    $year = date("Y");
    $url = "http://mlb.mlb.com/lookup/json/named.sport_pitching_composed.bam?game_type=%27R%27&sport_code=%27mlb%27&sort_by=%27season_asc%27&player_id={$id}&sport_pitching_composed.season=2014";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you access the other elements such as $season['hr']?

Comment: That error message means that `$season` is a string, not an array. You must have overwritten the variable somewhere. Post the rest of your code.

Comment: Can't access the other keys either. Code coming ...

Comment: Added a more accurate example above. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If you `var_dump($season)` in your foreach, what do you get?

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: Thanks Javad. You're onto something. I'm looping through all starting games and the dump shows some of the data is indeed showing up as strings. Looking into it ...

Comment: Looks like the problem was with my data. If a pitcher has more than one season its an array of seasons. If there's only one season it is not in a seasons array. I havn't 100% confirmed, but it looks like this fits the error. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. For the record fix is above.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my data wasn't consistently formated (sometimes an array was not nested).

Fixed it by changing:

```
public function getPitcherAvg($id)
{
    $stats = $this->getPitcherStats($id);
    $stats = $stats['sport_pitching_composed']['sport_pitching_agg']['queryResults']['row'];

    foreach ($stats as $season)
    {
        if ($season['season'] == 2014)
        {
            $avg = $season['avg'];
        }
    }

    return $avg;
}
```

To this:

```
public function getPitcherAvg($id)
{
    $stats = $this->getPitcherStats($id);
    $seasons = $stats['sport_pitching_composed']['sport_pitching_agg']['queryResults']['row'];

    foreach ($seasons as $key => $season)
    {
        if (!is_array($season))
        {
            if ($key == 'avg') $avg = $season;
        }           
        elseif ($season['season'] == 2014)
        {
            $avg = $season['avg'];
        }
    }

    return $avg;
}
```